# How to wrap anchor tag around list item? nedd the list item bullet

Tags: css, html-lists, anchor

i tried the whole thing with ul li and anchor tag but could not get the bullet inside the anchor tag. i tried with the table method and it works fine but that's just a hack.how to do it with ul li?

Comment: You can't wrap an `<a>` around an `<li>`. Permitted parent elements of `<li>`: An `<ul>`, `<ol>`, or `<menu>` element. [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li#Usage_context)

Comment: List style position :inside?

Comment: What effect should it have, what are you trying to create?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it this way:

```
<ul>
  <li><a ...></li>
  <li><a ...></li>
  <li><a ...></li>
</ul>
```

Nothing other is possible without scripting.